# How to modify the "after" of last element in wp_nav_menu 

Tags: navigation

When using wp_nav_menu how do I make it so 'after' => does not show on the last element of the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide it with CSS.  For example, if your `after` looks like:

```
<?php wp_nav_menu(array('after' => '<span>|</span>')); ?>
```

Then your css:

```
.menu-item-num span { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('#menu-top-menu-1').children().last().each( function(){
    var endHtml = $(this).html().replace('<text you want to replace>','<text to replace it with>');         
    $(this).html(endHtml);
});
```

Comment: Can't edit, but also need to change #menu-top-menu-1 to your menu ID

Answer (score 1):

While this can be done with JS, it might be more tidy to use `wp_nav_menu` filter, through which final output of menu is passed before returning/echoing.

Comment: You should expound on this

Answer (score 0):

Found this on another Answer

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/105562/105 , but this question came up first when searching; so cross linking for future searchers

```
add_filter('wp_nav_menu','replace_last_nav_item',100,2);
function replace_last_nav_item($items, $args) {
  return substr_replace($items, '', strrpos($items, $args->after), strlen($args->after));
}
```