# I want remove last after wp_nav_menu

Tags: menus

My code call menu:

```
$defaults = array(
    'theme_location'  => '',
    'menu'            => '',
    'container'       => 'div',
    'container_class' => true,
    'container_id'    => 'btn',
    'menu_class'      => true,
    'menu_id'         => '',
    'echo'            => true,
    'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
    'before'          => '',
    'after'           => '<li class="btn_bar"><img width="18" height="38" src="http://localhost/client/fzsytech/wp-content/themes/fzsytech/img/pic-btn_bar.jpg"></li>',
    'link_before'     => '',
    'link_after'      => '',
    'items_wrap'      => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
    'depth'           => 0,
    'walker'          => ''
);

wp_nav_menu( $defaults );

?>
```

And, my code when output :

```
<ul>
    <li id="menu-item-xx" class="blah blah">ABC</li>
    <li class="btn_bar"><img width="18" height="38" src="img/pic-btn_bar.jpg"></li>
    <li id="menu-item-xx" class="blah blah">DEF</li>
    <li class="btn_bar"><img width="18" height="38" src="img/pic-btn_bar.jpg"></li>
```

I want remove `<li class="btn_bar"><img width="18" height="38" src="img/pic-btn_bar.jpg"></li>` in the last menu ?

Comment: then do not use the line in `array`

Answer (score 3):

This will replace the last occurrence of your `after` string.

```
function replace_last_nav_item($items, $args) {
  return substr_replace($items, '', strrpos($items, $args->after), strlen($args->after));
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu','replace_last_nav_item',100,2);
```

Pure CSS will do this too:

```
.btn_bar:last-child{display:none}
```

Comment: Thank you very much. I follow your way and it was just the way my

Comment: If this solved the problem please mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
$after = '<li class="btn_bar"><img width="18" height="38" src="http://localhost/client/fzsytech/wp-content/themes/fzsytech/img/pic-btn_bar.jpg"></li>';
        $defaults = array(
                'theme_location'  => 'primary',
                'menu'            => '',
                'container'       => 'div',
                'container_class' => true,
                'container_id'    => 'btn',
                'menu_class'      => true,
                'menu_id'         => '',
                'echo'            => false,
                'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
                'before'          => '',
                'after'           => $after,
                'link_before'     => '',
                'link_after'      => '',
                'items_wrap'      => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
                'depth'           => 0,
                'walker'          => ''
            );

            $menu = wp_nav_menu( $defaults );  
            echo substr($menu, 0, strripos($menu, $after)).'</ul>';
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this code function.php

```
function replace_last_nav_item($items, $args) {
  return substr_replace($items, '', strrpos($items, $args->after), strlen($args->after));
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu','replace_last_nav_item',100,2);
```

Add this code menu

```
<?php
$defaults = array(
   'menu'            => 'footer-menu',
  'container'       => 'ul',
  'container_class' => '',
  'container_id'    => '',
  'menu_class'      => '',
  'menu_id'         => '',
  'echo'            => true,
  'fallback_cb'     => false,
  'before'          => '',
  'after'           => '&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;|&nbsp;',
  'link_before'     => '',
  'link_after'      => '',
  'items_wrap'      => '<ul>%3$s</ul>',
  'depth'           => 0,
  'walker'          => ''
  );
  wp_nav_menu( $defaults ); ?>
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your code. File an [edit] to add all relevant info to what your code does and how it works. Also, if you add code, indent each line with 4 spaces or highlight the code in the editor and click on the `{}` sign above the editor to add your code in a code block