# wp_nav_menu add something before closing container and after last list item

Tags: theme-development, menus

I've been looking for a way to hard code a `<div>` tag before the closing container tag of a particular menu:

```
$footer_nav = array(
    'menu'              => 'footer-menu',
    'menu_class'        => 'foobar',
    'container'         => 'ul',
    'theme_location'    => 'footer',
    'menu_id'           => 'footer_menu',
    'echo'              => true,
    'depth'             => 1,
);
wp_nav_menu( $footer_nav );
```

However when I try to add:

```
'after' => '<div class="foo">bar</div>',
```

it adds it after every list item.  When I researched for a solution I ran across [I want remove last after wp_nav_menu](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/105560/i-want-remove-last-after-wp-nav-menu) and [Wordpress Functions - How to use Replace String func. to add some code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23414636/wordpress-functions-how-to-use-replace-string-func-to-add-some-code) but when I try:

```
function foobar_the_menu($items,$args) {
    if ($args->theme_location == 'footer') {
        $footer_pattern     = '</li></ul>';
        $footer_replacement = '</li><div class="foo">bar</div></ul>';
        return substr_replace( $footer_pattern, $footer_replacement, $items, 1 );
    }
}
add_filter( 'wp_nav_menu', 'foobar_the_menu', 10, 2 );
```

It removes all the menus.  After referencing a few other questions I did see `wp_nav_menu_items` and `preg_replace` but I'm unsure what is the correct approach to target a particular menu to hard code a div since you cannot modify this in the menu array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use:

```
'items_wrap' => '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s <div class="foo">bar</div> </ul>',
```

as a `wp_nav_menu()` argument.

We're using this part of the `wp_nav_menu()` function:

```
$nav_menu .= sprintf( 
    $args->items_wrap, 
    esc_attr( $wrap_id ), 
    esc_attr( $wrap_class ), 
    $items 
);
```

where the `items_wrap` argument contains the following `sprintf` *specifiers*:

- `%1$s` to match the *wrap id*
- `%2$s` to match the *wrap class*
- `%3$s` to match the generated HTML for the *items*.

Comment: That worked, do you mind explaining what `%1$s`, `%2$s`  and `%3$s` are doing so I can understand the solution better?

Comment: Great, sure I updated the answer @DᴀʀᴛʜVᴀᴅᴇʀ

Comment: Thanks, I figured that could help someone in the future know what is going on, +1